# Как сделать чтобы не исчезал ProgressDialog при нажатии на клавиши типа HOME, BACK, SEARCH?

Tags: android, java, progress-bar

Здравствуйте. 
Пишу приложение на android в нем есть **ProgressDialog** который показывает прогресс выполнение некой задачи,как сделать чтобы он не исчезал при нажатии на кнопки **HOME**, **BACK**, **SEARCH**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/119023/) есть подборка различных решений. Мне лично нравиться третий вариант - когда прогресс попадает в область уведомлений. Для хорошего решения придется ещё сделать сервис, который будет это все обновлять. Пользователь сможет наблюдать прогресс, сможет работать с другими приложениями. А когда надумает - кликнет и откроет приложение снова.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать метод [**setCancelable(false)**](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29).
При нажатии на кнопку **BACK** ничего происходить не будет. При нажатии на **HOME** - приложение скроется, но после разварачивания **Dialog** останется на своём месте.

---

Иначе - никак, ваша программа будет ограничивать возможности пользователя.

Comment: Мне и надо ограничить,приложение связано с безопасностью,поэтому нужно запретить использование этих кнопок. Это я уже использую setCancelable(false), но мне нужно остальные клавиши заблокировать.

Comment: Это плохая идея. Не нужно ограничивать пользователя. Но если сильно нужно - делайте свою прошивку.

Comment: Я же сказал это сделана в целях безопасности. У меня приложение шифрует и дешифрует файлы. Допустим при нажатии на HOME приложение свернулось. "Злоумышленик" может взять устройство открыть приложение и шифровать и дешифровать данные.

Comment: нужно при открытии активити проверять и переспрашивать пароль.
Но не забывайте, что как только Ваше приложение будет свернуто, система может прибить его в любой момент. И файлы будут недошифрованы.

Comment: У меня в приложении заблокированы эти кнопки, при их нажатии выводится сообщение в виде Toast типа "Кнопка заблокирована в целях безопасности". Но когда появляется ProgressDialog они активны.

Comment: ну тогда просто внимательно посмотрите ссылку на хабр ниже. Может не нужно создавать прогресс-диалог, а просто отображать прогресс прямо на активити. Но я думаю, что все равно смогу "поломать" такую программу.

Comment: Т.е вы видете какую то уязвимость в этом,поясните?

Comment: в слепую сложно угадывать, но к примеру, я могу открыть notofication bar и оттуда зайти в настройки и, к примеру, закрыть программу. Или настроить доспуп по adb и в нужный момент прибить программу. Было бы желание.